# Is there a way to stop event propagation without passing message?

Tags: elm

I'd like to stop the event propagation on specific Html elements, but for this, I need to create a Placeholder Message. I found this post https://github.com/elm/html/issues/96 but it seems outdated and the recommendations do not work anymore.

Is there a nice way to achieve it? Unfortunately the never fn does not work.

My Current solution is:

```
  Html.Events.stopPropagationOn event (Json.Decode.succeed ( IgnoreEvent, True ))
```

Comment: Try a decoder that uses fail instead. I suspect that will NOT work, but you might be lucky

Comment: I tried. The issue here, you still need to pass a message, which is probably will be used for nothing.
Could not come up with a great idea yet.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think you need to provide more code and context so we can look for alternative approaches to the problem